# C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c, macos, osx-lion, macports, expat-parser

I installed OSx 1.6 and 1.7 (lion) today (1.5 was installed before). After this i reinstalled xcode and command line tools. Unistalled and cleand all ports from macport. When i try to install something from macports there is an error: (reinstalling xcode doesn't work)

```
--->  Computing dependencies for autoconf
--->  Dependencies to be installed: help2man gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses ncursesw p5.12-locale-gettext perl5.12 gdbm m4 perl5
--->  Configuring expat
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install expat
Log for expat is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: help2man gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses ncursesw p5.12-locale-gettext perl5.12 gdbm m4 perl5
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

Install log:

```
cat /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
version:1
:debug:main Attempting ln -sf /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/textproc/expat/work
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 500
:debug:main euid changed to: 501
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (expat)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch archivefetch phase started at Mon Feb 20 17:36:35 CET 2012
:msg:archivefetch --->  Fetching archive for expat
:debug:archivefetch Executing org.macports.archivefetch (expat)
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 0/0
:debug:archivefetch chowned /opt/local/var/macports/software/expat to macports
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 501/500
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 0/0
:debug:archivefetch chowned /opt/local/var/macports/incoming to macports
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 501/500
:info:archivefetch --->  expat-2.0.1_1.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macports/software/expat
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.0.1_1.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/expat
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed:: The requested URL returned error: 404
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:fetch fetch phase started at Mon Feb 20 17:36:37 CET 2012
:notice:fetch --->  Fetching expat
:debug:fetch euid/egid changed to: 0/0
:debug:fetch chowned /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/expat to macports
:debug:fetch euid/egid changed to: 501/500
:debug:fetch Executing org.macports.fetch (expat)
:debug:fetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:checksum checksum phase started at Mon Feb 20 17:36:37 CET 2012
:notice:checksum --->  Verifying checksum(s) for expat
:debug:checksum Executing org.macports.checksum (expat)
:info:checksum --->  Checksumming expat-2.0.1.tar.gz
:debug:checksum Correct (md5) checksum for expat-2.0.1.tar.gz
:debug:checksum Correct (sha1) checksum for expat-2.0.1.tar.gz
:debug:checksum Correct (rmd160) checksum for expat-2.0.1.tar.gz
:debug:checksum Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:extract extract phase started at Mon Feb 20 17:36:37 CET 2012
:notice:extract --->  Extracting expat
:debug:extract Executing org.macports.extract (expat)
:info:extract --->  Extracting expat-2.0.1.tar.gz
:debug:extract setting option extract.args to '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.0.1.tar.gz'
:debug:extract Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.7'
:debug:extract Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.0.1.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf -'
:debug:extract Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.0.1.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner -xf - 
:debug:extract euid/egid changed to: 0/0
:debug:extract chowned /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work to macports
:debug:extract euid/egid changed to: 501/500
:debug:extract Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:patch patch phase started at Mon Feb 20 17:36:37 CET 2012
:debug:patch Executing org.macports.patch (expat)
:debug:patch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:configure configure phase started at Mon Feb 20 17:36:37 CET 2012
:notice:configure --->  Configuring expat
:debug:configure Using compiler 'Mac OS X clang'
:debug:configure Executing org.macports.configure (expat)
:debug:configure Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64' CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include' CXXFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.7' CXX='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' F90FLAGS='-pipe -O2 -m64' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64' OBJC='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/clang' FCFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -m64' INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c' OBJCFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64' FFLAGS='-pipe -O2 -m64' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' CC='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/clang'
:debug:configure Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.0.1" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --mandir=/opt/local/share/man'
:debug:configure Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.0.1" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --mandir=/opt/local/share/man 
:info:configure checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
:info:configure checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
:info:configure checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/clang
:info:configure checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
:info:configure See `config.log' for more details.
:info:configure shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.0.1" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --mandir=/opt/local/share/man " returned error 77
:error:configure Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: the following items did not execute (for expat): org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:error:configure Failed to install expat
:debug:configure couldn't open "/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tclIndex": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open [file join $dir tclIndex]"
```

i tried to run: sudo port -f install tcl +headers, error:

```
:info:configure checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
:info:configure See `config.log' for more details.
:info:configure shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_tcl/tcl/work/tcl8.5.11/unix" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --disable-corefoundation tcl_cv_type_64bit="long long" " returned error 77
:error:configure Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: the following items did not execute (for tcl): org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:configure Log for tcl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_tcl/tcl/main.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macports doesn't work with Xcode 4.3

Answer (score 0):

The last lines of the log file say:

```
:debug:configure couldn't open "/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tclIndex": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open [file join $dir tclIndex]"
```

It looks as if there is something up with your installation of Tcl/Tk - it doesn't match something's expectations.  Either it isn't installed at all or it is the wrong version or ...

I suggest aiming to resolve that - or working out why `$dir` was set to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/` before continuing.